# Xcode 13.3.1 showing Build input files cannot be found error after changing my device

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift5, xcode13

I recently changed my device from iPhone 8 to an iPhone 13 mini and tried to run my app on it but xcode is failing and showing me Build input files cannot be found (in target 'QuestionBot' from project 'QuestionBot'). Also now when I try to run the code on my old iPhone or on a simulator it still shows me this error and refuses to run. My full code is available at: https://github.com/Capslockhuh/QuestionBot.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have pushed all the folders and files. Also, on your local machine check if you have correct references for each file and folder. I can see there is an issue with your folder reference. I have attached the screenshot for your reference.[image]